# SSL Certificate trust failure with Thrift Library

Tags: java, ios, cocoa, ssl, thrift

I want to access with an iOS client to a Java server. For the communication I used Thrift. If I build a connection, I get the following error message:

```
CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9807) 
Error occured opening stream: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-9807 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -9807.)"
Error TTransportException: Error writing to transport output stream.
userInfo = {
    error = "Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-9807 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (OSStatus error -9807.)\"";
}
```

The code of my iOS client:

```
TSSLSocketClient *transportSSL = [[TSSLSocketClient alloc] initWithHostname:_host port:_port];
TFramedTransport *mTransport = [[TFramedTransport alloc] initWithTransport:transportSSL];
TBinaryProtocol *protocol = [[TBinaryProtocol alloc]
                             initWithTransport:mTransport
                             strictRead:YES
                             strictWrite:YES];



TMultiplexedProtocol *profilePrtcl = [[TMultiplexedProtocol alloc] initWithProtocol:protocol serviceName:@"ProfileService"];
self.service = [[ProfileServiceClient alloc] initWithProtocol:profilePrtcl];
```

The Code of my Java Server:

```
TSSLTransportFactory.TSSLTransportParameters params = new TSSLTransportFactory.TSSLTransportParameters();
params.setKeyStore("/path/to/keystore.jks", "Password");
this.serverTransport = TSSLTransportFactory.getServerSocket(port,10000, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), params);
TServer server = new TThreadPoolServer(new TThreadPoolServer.Args(serverTransport).processor(processor));
server.serve()
```

Do I not add a certificate to the client?

**EDIT**

In the TSSLSocketClient is a method:

```
- (id) initWithHostname: (NSString *) hostname port: (int) port
```

On the line 91 can find following code:

```
NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(id)kCFBooleanTrue, (id)kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain, nil];
```

I´ve changed the code as follows:

```
NSDictionary *settings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                              kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates,
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                              kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot,
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],
                              kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain,
                              kCFNull,kCFStreamSSLPeerName,
                              nil];
```

and now I get the following error:

`Certificate trust failure
Cannot trust certificate. TrustResultType: 5`

Comment: you still requires more information?

Comment: Were we able to figure out a solution for this question?